# Why does my app not always sends messags to channels?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, slack-api

I have an `Account` model where account has many `Matter`. On creating matter, system send notification to a private slack channel configured with associated account.

On slack Incoming WebHooks configuration every channel has different hook url but I only configured one in to my app environment which seems not send messages always to all channels - `https://hooks.slack.com/services/TXXXXXX/BXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXX`

On matter creation callback code like below:

```
client = Slack::Notifier.new web_hook_url_from_environment_var
client.ping message, {channel: '#channel-name-configured-into-assoc-account'}
```

Should I configure/initialize associated channel's webhook url?

Answer (score 0):

The standard webhook is fixed to one channel. You can not change it. But there is an older variant that works with multiple channels and which you can install. See [Sending message to different channel via slack webhook fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51467215/sending-message-to-different-channel-via-slack-webhook-fails/51467673#51467673) for details.

In general I would suggest to use the API and [`chat.postMessage`](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage) for sending messages to multiple channel with your app.