# Slack Laravel Formatting

Tags: laravel, slack, slack-api

So notifications work no problems, on my user model i am routing to slack as such:

```
  /**
   * Route notifications for the Slack channel.
   *
   * @return string
   */
  public function routeNotificationForSlack()
  {
      return env('SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL');
  }
```

However when it comes time to make changes, the following from and to methods have no effect.

```
    return (new SlackMessage)
            ->from('Ghost', ':ghost:')
            ->to('#channel-name')
```

What do i need to do to post to another channel? and change the from would be nice!

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51467215/sending-message-to-different-channel-via-slack-webhook-fails/51467673#51467673